# mdframed does not attempt to stretch or shrink vertical spaces within its content

Tags: spacing, mdframed

When the content in an `mdframed` environment is overfull, `mdframed` will rather break the page instead of iteratively shrinking the vertical length up to the specified minimum.

The following output illustrates the problem; the framed environment on the left was generated using `mdframed`, which gave an `Overfull \vbox` warning, while that on the right was created using `framed`, which works as intended:

[image: mdframed vs framed overfull \vbox handling]

The corresponding preambles for both are

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=16cm,vscale=0.75,vcentering]{geometry}
\usepackage[ntheorem,framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{parskip}

% Modified theorem header
\makeatletter
    \def\theorem@checkbold{}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
    \renewtheoremstyle{break}%
        {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
            ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
        {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
            ##1\ ##2:\ ##3\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
\makeatother

% Remove extra vertical skip at the end of frames
\let\svendmdframed\endmdframed
\makeatletter
    \def\endmdframed{\svendmdframed\unskip}
\makeatother

% Definition
\theoremstyle{break}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremseparator{\medskip}
\newmdtheoremenv[%
    skipabove           = 2.0ex plus0.25ex minus0.25ex  ,%
    skipbelow           = 2.0ex plus0.25ex minus0.25ex  ,%
    leftmargin          = 0pt   ,%
    rightmargin         = 0pt   ,%
    innerleftmargin     = 10pt  ,%
    innerrightmargin    = 10pt  ,%
    innertopmargin      = 10pt  ,%
    innerbottommargin   = 10pt  ,%
    footnoteinside      = false ,%
    nobreak             = true  ,%
]{definition}{Definition}[section]
```

and

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=16cm,vscale=0.75,vcentering]{geometry}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[amsmath,framed]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{parskip}

% Modified theorem header
\makeatletter
    \def\theorem@checkbold{}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
    \renewtheoremstyle{break}%
        {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
            ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
        {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
            ##1\ ##2:\ ##3\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
\makeatother

% Definition
\theoremstyle{break}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremseparator{\medskip}
\newframedtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
```

respectively. The document content is

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{definition}[Basic set operations.]
        Donec vehicula augue euneque.

        \bigskip
        {\textbf{Set equality:}}\\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        \begin{equation}
            A + B = C.
        \end{equation}
        Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.

        \bigskip
        {\textbf{Set union:}}\\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        \begin{equation}
            A + B = C.
        \end{equation}
        Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.

        \bigskip
        {\textbf{Set intersection:}}\\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        \begin{equation}
            A + B = C.
        \end{equation}
        Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.

        \bigskip
        {\textbf{Set difference:}}\\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        \begin{equation}
            A + B = C.
        \end{equation}
        Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.

        \bigskip
        {\textbf{Set complement:}}\\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        \begin{equation}
            A + B = C.
        \end{equation}
        Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.

        \bigskip
        {\textbf{Cartesian product:}}\\
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
        \begin{equation}
            A + B = C.
        \end{equation}
    \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

So, the question is, is there a way to force `mdframed` to consider stretching or shrinking the vertical length before resorting to page break?

I use `mdframed` because `mdframed` provides better control of parameters over `framed`.

Comment: Try out tcolorbox instead. I have no idea if it works better in this respect, but as it is much more sophisticated then mdframed the chances are good. Something like this could be the starting point `\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{definition}{My Theorem}
{colframe=black,colback=white,fonttitle=\bfseries,breakable}{th}`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Stretchable vertical lengths within the content of a tcolorbox environment seem to work fine. Since completely switching from ntheorem + mdframed to tcolorbox is non-trivial for the existing documents, I would only resort to this solution if all else fails.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay, I am awestruck by the beautiful frames provided by `tcolorbox`, and proceeded to convert a total of 332 environments (definitions, theorems, corollaries and lemmata) across 19 files with a few clicks using regular expressions. If you would, please kindly write your suggestion as a short, proper answer. I am more than happy to accept it.

Comment: @PYK You should really also post your solution as an answer. It is not, after all, part of your question. (You can still accept Ulrike Fischer's answer, but yours can serve as a more detailed extension of that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out `tcolorbox` instead. I have no idea if it works better in this respect, but as it is much more sophisticated then `mdframed` the chances are good. Something like this could be the starting point

```
 \usepackage[many]{tcolorbox} 
 \newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{definition}{My Theorem} 
  {colframe=black,colback=white,fonttitle=\bfseries,breakable}{th}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have switched from using `ntheorem + mdframed` to `ntheorem + tcolorbox`, as the `breakable` library from `tcolorbox` has an advanced algorithm which tests whether or not a frame fits in a page by stretching or shrinking vertical spaces within its content before resorting to splitting the frame.

In case anyone would like to switch as well, here are some tips:

### Shared counters

Instead of creating a new counter, you can access the counter initialized by a `tcolorbox` environment using the counter name `tcb@cnt@<name>` ([tcolorbox 3.50, page 94](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en)). For example, the following code

```
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

% tcolorbox 'Definition' environment
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{definition}{Definition}{}{def}

% ntheorem 'Example' environment
\makeatletter
    \newtheorem{example}[tcb@cnt@definition]{Example}
\makeatother
```

enables the counter from a `tcolorbox` environment to be reused in an `ntheorem` environment.

### Regex for converting `ntheorem` to `tcolorbox` environments

A typical `ntheorem` environment with `hyperref` would look like this:

```
\begin{theorem}[Leibniz formula for determinants.]\phantomsection\label{thm:leibniz_formula}
```

In order to convert the above syntax to a `tcolorbox`-compatible syntax like so

```
\begin{theorem}{Leibniz formula for determinants.}{leibniz_formula}
```

one could use the following regular expressions:

Match

```
(?<=(\\begin\{theorem\}))\[(.*?)\]\\phantomsection\\label\{thm:(.*?)\}
```

and replace the saved matching strings with

```
\{\2\}\{\3\}
```

Adapt the regex to suit your own needs. Most editors have a built-in regular expressions support.

### Edit

For the sake of completeness, here is an example of the result of the conversion:

[image: ntheorem + tcolorbox]

The nice corollary frame is provided by `tcolorbox`; the ensuing proof and example with their neat endmarks are provided `ntheorem`. Notice the shared counter.

Also note that `tcolorbox` automatically trims the extra vertical space arising from ending the frame content with an `amsmath equation` environment.

`tcolorbox` is nice.